# Localization error - part of UI is in wrong language

Tags: bug, user-interface, site-ads

I opened stackoverflow from google search results (I'm googling in English) and I saw a big banner with text neither in English nor in my native language (which is Ukrainian). IP location says that I'm in Ukraine, Lviv, so I have no idea why I see that weird banner. I think it may be a bug.
[image]

Comment: That is an ad and some ads are targeted based on users location. I get ads in Dutch. The company offering the ad probably assumes that Russian is okay for your location.

Comment: Is it an add? Are they allowed to use the SO logo as a watermark in ads? If it actually is a 3rd party ad then it's not under SO's control but without knowing what the text say it's hard to know.

Comment: @ivarni my Russian is sub-par ... I have no idea what it is offering ...

Comment: From [Grundy in ro.chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51120695#51120695): on image: *Not find a solution? Ask a question* 
text on button: *ask question* so I think it is safe to assume it is an ad from SO headquarters themselves.

Comment: @rene, methinks, question not in text content, but in language: op was expeting text on ukrainian, but get in russian.

Comment: language can detect by browser language, if you have somewhere ru-RU - SO think you a russian-speaking, and show banner. Just because SO have "SO на русском", и doesn't have "SO на украинском"

Comment: This looks like SE's internal ads for their localized SO. From a quick research, I found 25% of Ukrainians can speak Russian, so I think it's a deliberate choice to advertise about their localized SO in Russian...

Comment: Either way, I think there is grammatical error. It should say `Задайте свой вопрос`, not  `Задайте ваш вопрос`

Comment: @Wilson, both variant are valid

Comment: @AndrewT. (not as a contradiction, but as an additional insight) that survey was probably asking people what language they spoke, not what languages they know. Recent political movements have led many people in Ukraine to switch to speaking Ukrainian in public and with their children even when it's not their most fluent language. ~70% of Ukrainians considered Russian a native language as of late 2000's, including even a slim majority of people living in Kyiv, the capital. Lviv is one of the few parts of Ukraine where even educated people often can't speak Russian.

Comment: @Jeutnarg education !== knowledge of Russian. I'm originally from a city that located 100km from Kyiv and I had only 1 year of learning Russian back in 2008 or so, and that was the last year we had Russian as subject in ukrainian schools (or at least in my school). In Lviv most people don't learn Russian in schools, don't speak it, and generally don't need it, while they have pretty good education.

Comment: @MykolaMoroziuk It's a very strong correlation outside of the Western oblasts, outside of which, college-educated Ukrainians can speak Russian. Most of them would have to in order to even attend university, since so many of the courses are taught in that language. It's not a one-sided situation, though. In the Eastern oblasts and in Crimea, educated Ukrainians often can't speak Ukrainian. They may be able to read it and handle some literature, but that's it. Overall, the leaning is toward Russian: the 2008 Gallup poll showed that 83% of Ukrainians preferred to fill out the form in Russian.

Comment: @Jeutnarg I see, yes, probably you know better what's going on in Ukraine than a person who lives there for the entire life.

Comment: @MykolaMoroziuk Why is that so strange to you? You would struggle to read a newspaper in Lugansk, so why couldn't a foreigner who speaks Russian and lived in that region for over a year know it better than you? Soon, god willing, when peace returns to your country, I hope you get a chance to go to the East and see what the language landscape is like there. Especially important for the point you are arguing, try and find an educated adult in Eastern Ukraine that can't speak Russian. I'd suggest trying in Kyiv also, but the political situation is likely to skew the responses.

Comment: @MykolaMoroziuk either way, this would probably be a better topic for Linguistics, Travel (perhaps "Which language, Russian or Ukrainian, will be more widely understood on my trip to Ukraine?"), or Language Learning.